# Positioning image based on div position

Tags: html, css

I've got a div somewhere closer to the center of the page. Below is the div structure.

```
<div id="newsFeed">
   <img id="thumb" src="news/news123.png" height=50 width=50 />
</div>
```

css:

```
#newsFeed{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#thumb{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

How can I move the image 20px to the right from the current position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shift the image to the right by setting its `margin-left` to 20px. This will add 20px space to the left of the image, giving impression that image is shifted 20px to the right.

```
#thumb {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Demo

```css
#newsFeed {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#thumb {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsFeed">
  <img id="thumb" src="news/news123.png" height=50 width=50 />
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can also set the `left` to 20px.

```
#thumb {
    ....
    left: 20px;
}
```

Demo

```css
#newsFeed {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#thumb {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsFeed">
  <img id="thumb" src="news/news123.png" height=50 width=50 />
</div>
```

Comment: `padding-left` won't work in this case since the parent div does not have any height.